# How to programmatically draw a thick line JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I'm trying to define `racecourse` with a dynamic line that user can draw on a canvas element. So when line has been drawn, program should add sidelines for it as shown in the picture below:

[image: idea of the result]

I have managed to mimic the idea already by using line normals but can't get it done correctly. At the moment I put point in the midway of the lines in the direction of the line normals and draw outlines using those points. While generated line is relatively smooth in cases on large turns, tight turns tend to produce loops.

As seen in image below:

[image: current state of result]

Here is current code that generates points for side lines above (I'm using p5.js JavaScript library):

```js
var sketch = function (p) {
  with(p) {

    let handpoints;
    let walkhandpoints;
    let collect;
    let parsepath;
    let shapse;
    let step;
    let tmp; 
    let dorender;
    let lineoffset;

    p.setup = function() {
      createCanvas(600, 600);
      handpoints = [];
      walkhandpoints = 10;
      collect = true;
      parsepath = false;
      shapes = [];
      step = 2;
      tmp = [];
      dorender = true;
      lineoffset = 15;
    };

    p.draw = function() {
      if(dorender) {
        background(220);
        update();
        for (let shape of shapes) {
          shape.show();
        }
      }
    };

    function update() {
      if (mouseIsPressed) {
        if (collect) {
          let mouse = createVector(mouseX, mouseY);
          handpoints.push(mouse);
          Shape.drawPath(handpoints);
          parsepath = true;
        }
      } else if (parsepath) {
        let tmp1 = Shape.cleanPath(handpoints, step);
        let s1 = new Shape(tmp1, 1, 'line', color(175));
        shapes.push(s1);
        let tmp2 = Line.sidePoints(tmp1, lineoffset);
        let s2 = new Shape(tmp2.sideA, 1, 'line', color(175,120,0));
        let s3 = new Shape(tmp2.sideB, 1, 'line', color(175,0, 120));
        shapes.push(s2);
        shapes.push(s3);
        handpoints = [];
        parsepath = false;
        //dorender = false;
      }
    }

    class Shape {
      constructor(points, mag, type = 'line', shader = color(200, 0, 100)) {
        this.points = points.slice().map(item => item.copy());
        this.type = type;
        this.mag = mag;
        this.shader = shader;
      }

      static cleanPath(points, step) {
        let tmp = [];
        let output = [];
        for (let i = 1; i < points.length; i++) {
          let prev = points[i - 1];
          let curr = points[i];
          if (!prev.equals(curr)) {
            tmp.push(prev.copy())
            if (i === points.length - 1) {
              tmp.push(curr.copy())
            }
          }
        }
        for (let i = 0; i < tmp.length; i++) {
          if(i % step === 0) {
            output.push(tmp[i]);
          }
        }
        output.push(output[0]);
        return output;
      }
  
      static drawPath(points, mag = 1, type = 'line', shader = color(175)) {
        let s = new Shape(points, mag, type, shader);
        s.show();
      }
  
      show() {

        for (let i = 0; i < this.points.length; i++) {
          if (this.type === 'line' && i > 0) {
            let prev = this.points[i - 1];
            let curr = this.points[i];
            strokeWeight(this.mag);
            stroke(this.shader);
            line(prev.x, prev.y, curr.x, curr.y);
          } else if (this.type === 'point') {
            noStroke();
            fill(this.shader);
            ellipse(this.points[i].x, this.points[i].y, this.mag * 2, this.mag * 2);
          }
        }
      }
    }

    class Line {
      static sidePoints(points, lineoffset) {
        let sideA = [];
        let sideB = [];
        for(let i = 1; i < points.length; i++) {

          // take consecutive points
          let prev = points[i-1];
          let curr = points[i];

          // calculate normals
          let dx = curr.x-prev.x;
          let dy = curr.y-prev.y;
          let a = createVector(-dy, dx).normalize();
          let b = createVector(dy, -dx).normalize();

          // calculate midway of the two points
          let px = (prev.x+curr.x)/2;
          let py = (prev.y+curr.y)/2;
          let p = createVector(px,py);
      
          // put created points back along drawed line
          a.mult(lineoffset).add(p);
          b.mult(lineoffset).add(p);
          sideA.push(a);
          sideB.push(b);
        }

        // close paths
        if(!sideA[0].equals(sideA[sideA.length-1])) {
          sideA.push(sideA[0]);
        }
        if(!sideB[0].equals(sideB[sideB.length-1])) {
          sideB.push(sideB[0]);
        }
        return {sideA, sideB};
      }
    }


  }
};

let node = document.createElement('div');
window.document.getElementById('p5-container').appendChild(node);
new p5(sketch, node);
```

```css
body {
  background-color:#ffffff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.1.9/p5.js"></script>
    <div id="p5-container"></div>
```

- Firstly I'd like to find a way to draw those points in the corresponding corner points of the drawn line so when drawn line has only few points the outlines would retain the drawn shape.
- Secondly is there some good way to reduce points on the areas where there are several of them to reduce those loops in small corners and other type errors in generated lines?
- Idea is to get points for lines, so it would be easy to detect with line intersection if race car velocity vector crosses it.
- Unfortunately I'm not very familiar with math notations so please try to use easy to understand version of them if there is some fancy math that would do the job.

Comment: Can you show the rest of the code (sketch) that you have this far.

Comment: Here is whole sketch so far https://editor.p5js.org/lazydistribution/sketches/r60EQ2cVg

Comment: Actually you want to compute the "parallel" contours.

Comment: Yes. That sounds basically what I'm trying to do.

Comment: First your code crashes if you just click.  It's trivial but people will try correct that bug instead of helping you on the algorithm.

Comment: One place where you optimize is on straight lines.  So if the difference in slopes (angles of a p5 vector) is below a threshold you could drop the center point.

Comment: You have to keep 2 sets of points: the user points and an optimized version of them.  For jitters, use a parameter that will serve as a threshold (a radius) where all the points that are too close will merge.

Comment: Once all those optimizations are done, you will be left with corners to optimize. I would suggest trying to fit a Bezier curve.

Comment: @DominiqueFortin *"First your code crashes [...]"* - the code works fine for me.

Comment: @Rabbid76 If you click and don't move the mouse, you get the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'copy' of undefined`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the error @DominiqueFortin -> fixed.

Comment: You need to implement miter joints to prevent the looping effect caused by joining overlapping end points. Google "polylines normals miter" to find out more. If you then click on image search you'll see some sample images with perfect joints and clicking those will likely lead you to a solution.

Answer (score 1):

In the future, please try to post a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I was not able to run your code as you posted it.

That being said, one option you could consider is using the `strokeWeight()` function to draw the path at different widths. Here's an example:

```js
const path = [];

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  
  // Add some default points to the path.
  path.push(createVector(0, 0));
  path.push(createVector(width/4, height/4));
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  
  // Draw the path with a thick gray line.
  strokeWeight(50);
  stroke(200);
  for(let i = 1; i < path.length; i++){
    const prevPoint = path[i-1];
    const nextPoint = path[i];
    line(prevPoint.x, prevPoint.y, nextPoint.x, nextPoint.y);
  }
 
  // Draw the path with a thin black line.
  strokeWeight(1);
  stroke(0);
  for(let i = 1; i < path.length; i++){
    const prevPoint = path[i-1];
    const nextPoint = path[i];    
     line(prevPoint.x, prevPoint.y, nextPoint.x, nextPoint.y);
  }
}

// Add a point to the path when the user clicks.
function mousePressed(){
 path.push(createVector(mouseX, mouseY));
}
```

[image: path]

The trick here is to draw the path in two passes. First you draw the path using a thick line, and then you draw the path again, this time using a thin line.

Comment: Thank you @KevinWorkman . I'll try to do that minimal example in the future. But while I need at least 2 lines for each side of the "road", strokeWeight() just changes pixel representation of a single line on the center of the "road".

Comment: @lazydistribution Why do you need two lines?

Comment: My idea was to detect with line intersection if the velocity vector of the race car crosses the road bench to know that the game is over.

Comment: @lazydistribution You could do collision detection with the thick line that was drawn as a result of my suggestion.

Comment: how would I do that?

Comment: @lazydistribution You might start by reading up on collision detection. One approach that comes to mind is using the thick line as a mask and then checking the pixels of that mask, but there are probably smarter ways to do it.

Comment: Thanks. I'm aware that collision detection by pixels can be made, but I thought it's slower than make intersection test with lines. At least as I know using pixels you need to test every pixel under velocity vector to test if the point is of the road while line intersection point with sideline and velocity vector can be calculated relatively fast. Or is there some algorithm that could generate sidelines using that pixel detection? Or Is this pixel detection as fast as line intersection test?

Comment: Of course there may be way to draw thick line with lineWeight(), take a snapshot from  the canvas, and using marching squares to generate the outer lines of the thick line of the snapshot, but that is lot of more work what I wish I don't have to do. But of course I will if needed.